# Accidentally viewing markup characters in vim `:help`

Tags: vim

I just created a .txt file inside `.vim/doc` for documenting one little function of my `.vimrc`, ran `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` and apparently the whole vim help system went wild. Now, if I open for example `:help help`, I see things like:

```
This also works together with other characters, for
example to find help for CTRL-V in Insert mode: >
      :help i^V
<
```

(notice the < and > characters). I can also see the `~` at the end of headlines and the modeline at the end of the help page (thinks like `vim:tw=78:ts=8:ft=help:norl:`).

I have no idea about what happens or how to fix it. Any clue?

Comment: If it was working as expected before, running :helptags should not have caused this issue. Is there *any* more information you can provide? Have you restarted Vim? What version of Vim?

Comment: Vim version: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jun 24 2011 20:00:09)
Compiled by root@apple.com`

Comment: Yes, I restarted vim, but still the same. I don't know what else can I tell you... the odd thing is that vim is not reading the help modeline. I don't know what could happened.

Comment: Well, another clue: I just notice that with the gui version of macvim the help pages show properly.

Comment: What does ":verbose set modeline? modelines?" (with the question marks) show? If you see "nomodeline" or "modelines=0" that would be why Vim is ignoring the help file modelines.

Comment: Could this be a colour scheme issue? If I do `colo default` then the markup disappears. I'm using solarized.

Answer (score 0):

> I just created a .txt file inside .vim/doc for documenting one little function of my .vimrc

So you modified `.vimrc` as well, right? Then run `:messages` and see if there are any errors reported when your `.vimrc` is loaded.

If that does not help, try running with `-V` (`-V` for verbose) so you have better clue what's going on.